# PHP preg_replace 'e' modifier dilemma

Tags: php, regex

I've been fighting with this for a few days now and it looks like I really have to ask someone else.

For the purposes of this thread, here is the problem: I am trying to manipulate a string using PHP's preg_replace and the 'e' modifier to execute a function within it. I want to change any instance of `[pdf]somefilename[/pdf]` to `<a href="somefilename.pdf">PDF</a> size('somefilename.pdf');`

So, for example maybe `[pdf]somefilename[/pdf]` would output a link to the file followed by (137MB).

For some reason, however, the (137MB) part is being put at the *beginning* of the entire string, instead of where it's supposed to be. It seems like `preg_replace` is evaluating everything, then going back and executing the function and just throwing the result in the beginning of the string.

So if I had `Some text blah, blah. Download the document: [pdf]somefilename[/pdf]` the regular expression outputs `(137MB) Some text blah, blah. Download the document: [link to document]` when it *should* output `Some text blah, blah. Download the document [link to document] (137MB)`.

I'm lost. Google can't save me. Someone please help!

Thanks in advance,
Jeff

Here's the code:

```
$bbcode_pdf_tag = '/\[pdf\](.*?)\[\/pdf\]/ie';
$html_pdf_tag = '"<a href=\"$1.pdf\">PDF</a>" .size("\\1.pdf")';
$decoded_data = preg_replace($bbcode_pdf_tag, $html_pdf_tag, $data);
```

EDIT: It's worth mentioning that size() is defined in a completely different file and this doesn't seem to happen when I use a built-in function such as strtolower(). Defining the size() function internally and using preg_replace_callback does not solve the problem.

Comment: psst, posting the code (or at least the regular expression) would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing what you're doing.  Please *actually provide the code*.

Comment: Please post your `preg_replace` call so we can take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use preg_replace_callback instead! 'e' option can be dangerous. Example with preg_replace_callback :

```
preg_replace_callback('`\[pdf\]([^\[]+)\[/pdf\]`i', function ($matches) { return "<a href=\"{$matches[1]}\">PDF</a> " . filesize($matches[1]); }, $string);
```

You can obviously make a more elaborate function that checks if the file exists or whatever. This code uses PHP 5.3 anonymous function, so if you don't run on PHP 5.3, you have to use the older syntax.

Edit: I wrote this answer before seeing the comments and OP's edited post, so I may have missed something.

Edit2: What is your size function? It looks like it prints the value instead of returning it.

```
function test() {
    echo "world";
}

echo "hello " . test(); // worldhello
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I am aware of the dangers of the 'e' modifier, and have written a version using callback but have exactly the same problem.

Comment: If I var_dump the result (`$string = "blabla [pdf]test.php[/pdf] blabla";`) : `string(44) "blabla PDF 882 blabla"`. The problem probably lies somewhere else.

Comment: I just thought about something. Does your size() function prints the value instead of returning it ? `echo "hello" . print("world"); // worldhello1`

Comment: Oh my goodness! I never even figured to check that size() printed a value instead of returning one, but that was the problem. I have it set up to return a value now and have no problems. Thank you so much!